# Cast from string (text) to varbinary

Tags: string, vb.net, casting, varbinary

I have problem with casting string into varbinary. In this code, I would like to write some data in database:

```
Private Sub insert_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles insert.Click
        Dim myconnect As New SqlClient.SqlConnection
        myconnect.ConnectionString = "Data Source=(localdb)\Projects;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False"


        Dim mycommand As SqlClient.SqlCommand = New SqlClient.SqlCommand()
        mycommand.Connection = myconnect
        mycommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Table (name, answer1, answer2, answer3, picture, voice) VALUES (@mname, @ans1, @ans2, @ans3, @pic, @sound)"
        myconnect.Open()

        Try
            mycommand.Parameters.Add("@mname", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox1.Text
            mycommand.Parameters.Add("@ans1", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox2.Text
            mycommand.Parameters.Add("@ans2", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox3.Text
            mycommand.Parameters.Add("@ans3", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox4.Text
            mycommand.Parameters.Add("@pic", SqlDbType.Image).Value = TextBox5.Text
            mycommand.Parameters.Add("@sound", SqlDbType.VarBinary).Value = TextBox6.Text
            mycommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
            MsgBox("Success")
        Catch ex As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
        myconnect.Close()
        TextBox1.Clear()
        TextBox2.Clear()
        TextBox3.Clear()
        TextBox4.Clear()
        TextBox5.Clear()
        TextBox6.Clear()
    End Sub
```

I get [this](http://prntscr.com/f52jq4) error.

I was trying to solve the problem with this code, but I get the same error:

```
Dim value As String = TextBox6.Text
Dim array() As Byte = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(value)
```

Also, this code did not work for me:

```
INSERT INTO Table (name, answer1, answer2, answer3, picture, voice) VALUES (@mname, @ans1, @ans2, @ans3, @pic, convert(varbinary(max), @sound))
```

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Your `@pic` parameter is also going to expect a byte array, so perhaps your fix of using `Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes` is "working" for `@sound`.  I say "working" in quotes because it seems unlikely that encoding a text string is going to give you a sound or picture.  What is being entered into the text boxes - a file name?  If so, perhaps what you need is [`File.ReadAllBytes`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readallbytes(v=vs.110).aspx), e.g. `mycommand.Parameters.Add("@sound", SqlDbType.VarBinary).Value = File.ReadAllBytes(TextBox6.Text)`.

Comment: I will try your proporsal. In text boxes are going paths to the .mp3 or .jpg files.  You are thinking that this solution will not working? I want to save some pictures and voice files to database,  so I find this way.

Comment: Path like this: `C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Penguins.jpg`